# Get data and append it to list until finished

Tags: haskell

I am working with the `Commit` type of `hit` package.
I have the next function but i want for it to return a list with all the `ref`s from `loopTillEmpty` function not only print them. Is that possible?

```
getRefs revision git = do
    ref <- maybe (error "revision cannot be found") id <$> resolveRevision git revision
    loopTillEmpty ref
    where loopTillEmpty ref = do
            commit <- getCommit git ref
            putStrLn $ show ref
            case commitParents commit of
                []    -> return ()
                (p:_) -> loopTillEmpty p
```

A sample output is

```
5cecfbca98fbc4b02b06ea315a857c97605ef135
e6e4a017be111eba85baad539c502bae2dacb14e
()
```

this shows us the refs and it return `()` when empty. The datatype looks like:

```
Commit {commitParents = []} -- when empty
Commit {commitParents = [e6e4a017be111eba85baade]} -- when not empty
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well right now you are printing in output the refs when you visit them and then loop. What you need is to accumulate those refs instead of printing them and that's the perfect task for a list. The important bits:

```
getRefs :: Revision -> Git -> IO [Ref]
getRefs revision git = do
    ref <- maybe (error "revision cannot be found") id <$> resolveRevision git revision
    loopTillEmpty ref
  where loopTillEmpty ref = do
          commit <- getCommit git ref
          nextRefs <- case commitParents commit of
                            []    -> return []
                            (p:_) -> loopTillEmpty p
          return $ ref : nextRefs
```

So your base case is `return []`, when there are no more refs after the current one, and `loopTillEmpty p` in the other case. The last line combines the current `ref` with the `nextRefs` into the resultant list. You can then `map show` on the result of `getRefs` to get the list of commits strings.

Answer (score 2):

You have to accumulate the items yourself like this:

```
where loopTillEmpty ref items = do
        commit <- getCommit git ref
        putStrLn $ show ref
        case commitParents commit of
            []    -> return items
            (p:_) -> loopTillEmpty p (ref:items)
```

and then call it with:

```
items <- loopTillEmpty ref []
```

Note - this accumulates the items in reverse order. It you need in the visited order just reverse it before using it or just before returning it, e.g.:

```
case commitParents commit of
  []    -> return (reverse items)
  (p:_) -> ...
```